# How to dynamically toggle class to a div when all fields with required class are filled?

Tags: jquery, html, css

In my form i have 2 select boxes and some text inputs. All of my required fields have the class "required". How can i check with jQuery if all of the required fields are not empty and toggle the class "disabled" in the "Next Step" button ?

```css
.category-select {
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  width:140px;
}

.color-select {
  display:block;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  width:140px;
}

.disabled {
  color:#aaa!important;
  background:#ddd!important;
}

.next-step-btn {
  width:140px;
  padding:15px;
  color:#fff;
  background:#0088cc;
  text-align:center;
  cursor:pointer;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-family:arial;
  font-size:12px;
  margin-top:50px;
}
```

```html
<select id="select_1" name="select_1" class="category-select required">
<option value="0">Select category</option>
<option value="1">Phones</option>
<option value="2">Computers</option>
<option value="3">Tablets</option>
</select>

<select id="select_2" name="select_2" class="color-select required">
<option value="8">Select a color</option>
<option value="9">White</option>
<option value="10">Blue</option>
<option value="11">Green</option>
</select>

<input class="required" placeholder ="Add some text..." type="text"/>

<div class="next-step-btn disabled">
NEXT STEP
</div>
```

Comment: you can use  condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$('select,input').change(function() {
  var s = $('.required').filter(function() {
    if ($(this).is("select")) {
      return $(this).val() == "";
    }
    if ($(this).is("input")) {
      return $(this).val().length == 0;
    }
  });
  if (s.length == 0)
    $(".next-step-btn").removeClass("disabled");
  else
    $(".next-step-btn").addClass("disabled");
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$('select,input').on("change keyup", function() {
  var s = $('.required').filter(function() {
    if ($(this).is("select")) {
      return $(this).val() == "";
    }
    if ($(this).is("input")) {
      return $(this).val().length == 0;
    }
  });
  if (s.length == 0)
    $(".next-step-btn").removeClass("disabled");
  else
    $(".next-step-btn").addClass("disabled");
});
```

```css
.category-select {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 140px;
}

.color-select {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 140px;
}

.disabled {
  color: #aaa!important;
  background: #ddd!important;
}

.next-step-btn {
  width: 140px;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  background: #0088cc;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select_1" name="select_1" class="category-select required">
  <option value="">Select category</option>
  <option value="1">Phones</option>
  <option value="2">Computers</option>
  <option value="3">Tablets</option>
</select>

<select id="select_2" name="select_2" class="color-select required">
  <option value="">Select a color</option>
  <option value="9">White</option>
  <option value="10">Blue</option>
  <option value="11">Green</option>
</select>

<input class="required" placeholder="Add some text..." type="text" />

<div class="next-step-btn disabled">
  NEXT STEP
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome!! Is it possible also to fire the event when someone start type in input text fields?

Comment: @Designer Added keyup

Comment: Thank you very much for your effort and your time. It works perfect ! i just accepted your answer ;)